# Different section header depending on section in collection view

Tags: swift

I have a collection view that needs to display a different kind of header depending on which section for my collection view.

However, when I add my second reusable view to my storyboard, it automatically takes that as my footer view.

Is there any way I can have two different section header for my collection view?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it programatically to `dequeue` the `headerView` programatically. Something like the below will help you:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                         viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                         at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        var headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind,
                   withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderOne",
                   for: indexPath) as! HeaderOneView
        if sectionTwo {
            headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind,
                   withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderTwo",
                   for: indexPath) as! HeaderTwoView
        }

        return headerView
    default:
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
   }
}
```

Also you might have to use this [function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618103-register) `register(_:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:)` to register a view that is created not via `storyboard`.